# Reactjs bind() for function with two parameters

Tags: reactjs

As you know, bind is not recommended for rendering. Instead, the bind is added in the constructor.

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
 
  handleClick(event){
    // your event handling logic
  }
 
  render(){
    return (
      <button type="button" 
      onClick={this.handleClick}>
      Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

But what about a function with two parameters? **handleClick(a, event)**

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
 
  handleClick(a, event){
    // your event handling logic
  }
 
  render(){
    return (
      <button type="button" 
      onClick={this.handleClick}>
      Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using an arrow function and it works, but I'm not sure if it's correct. I am expecting the right decision.

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
  }
 
  handleClick(a, event){
    // your event handling logic
  }
 
  render(){
    return (
      <button type="button" 
      onClick={(e) => this.handleClick('1',e)}>
      Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The arrow function would be the appropriate way to handle this most likely. `onClick` only passes an event to its handler, so if you need additional custom parameters passed to your handler, you will need an intermediate function like this arrow function.

Comment: It's mostly unrelated to binding. By using an arrow function you just happened to lose the requirement to find the function to `this`.

Comment: What's the best way? Convert the function itself handleClick() to a arrow function and then just call it in onClick? Or is my last option more correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding and using the constructor, the recommended way is using [class properties](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render) or writing modern React with function components.

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  // Auto binded
  handleClick = (a, event) => {
  }
 
  ...
}
```

In your case, you can just make a high order function:

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  // Auto binded
  genHandleClick = param => event => {
  }
 
  return <div onClick={this.genHandleClick(1)}/>
}
```

Comment: ... and onClick={?} - how to call an arrow function with parameters in onСlick?

Comment: You can try currying... See updated answer

Comment: onClick={this.genHandleClick(1) -  error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: Please just make a sandbox example instead of pasting errors in comments

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a beginner. Tell me, is your solution the best option? Or is your solution the same with my latest code?

Comment: There is no such thing as "best solution", it depends on the context and is mainly opinioned. In my opinion, it's a helpful pattern using currying.

Comment: I meant that this is a better solution than using a bind() in the render?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't bind in render, search for good practices in React Docs FAQ section.